# PivotTable not appear as expected

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I had been requested to make macro code for a `PivotTable`. I already done it but there is some error which I don't know about making the function called after this function `AgingFur` cannot been executed. The pivot also did not display as I expected.

Below is the PivotTable that I got (`Pivot Table A`):

[image]

Meanwhile this is the one that I should get (`Pivot Table B`), which generated manually:

[image]

Here is the code I used to make `Pivot Table A` :

```
Sub AgingFur()
    Sheets("B_Original COpy").Activate
    Dim objTable As PivotTable, objField As PivotField, ws As Worksheet
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("B_Original COpy").Range("A1").Select

    Set ws = Sheets.Add
    ws.Name = "X_Aging ST Inc"

    Set objTable = Sheets("B_Original COpy").PivotTableWizard(TableDestination:=ws.Cells(1, "A"))
    objTable.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlmissingItemNone
    objTable.PivotCache.Refresh

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Status")
    objField.Orientation = xlPageField
    objField.Position = 1
    objField.PivotItems("Cancelled").Visible = False

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Month Opened")
    objField.Orientation = xlRowField

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Age")
    objField.Orientation = xlDataField
    objField.Function = xlAverage
    objField.NumberFormat = "* #,##0.00"

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Age FL")
    objField.Orientation = xlDataField
    objField.Function = xlAverage
    objField.NumberFormat = "* #,##0.00"

    With objTable.DataPivotField
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

I need to appear the Pivot as `Pivot Table B` and need to resolve the error which I don't know where it is. Please ignore the values shown.

How can I solve this?

The code before function `AgingFur` is

```
Call KPIDashboardSheet    '<~ This one is Pivot
Call KPISecond            '<~ This one is Pivot
Call FactorizeData        '<~ This one is Pivot
Call AgingFur             '<~ The problem Pivot
Call SortWorksheets       '<~ This one for sort all sheets based on name
```

This is 'FactorizeData' code :

```
Private Sub FactorizeData()
Sheets("FactorizeData List").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A:AM").Copy
Sheets.Add.Name = "FactorizeData"
Sheets("FactorizeData List").Activate
Range("A:AM").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Call FactorizeDataTables
End Sub

Private Sub FactorizeDataTables()
Sheets("FactorizeData List").Activate
Dim objTable As PivotTable, objField As PivotField, ws As Worksheet
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("FactorizeData List").Range("A1").Select

Set ws = Sheets.Add
ws.Name = "FactorizeData Table"

Set objTable = Sheets("FactorizeData List").PivotTableWizard(TableDestination:=ws.Cells(3, "A"))
objTable.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlmissingItemNone
objTable.PivotCache.Refresh

Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Priority")
objField.Orientation = xlColumnField

Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Status")
objField.Orientation = xlColumnField

Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Type")
objField.Orientation = xlColumnField

Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Date")
objField.Orientation = xlRowField

Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Type")
objField.Orientation = xlDataField

Dim pf As PivotField
Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Date")
pf.DataRange.Cells(1).Group Start:=True, End:=True, Periods:=Array(False, False, _
False, False, True, False, True)
End Sub
```

This is the SortWorksheet :

```
Private Sub SortWorksheets()

Dim N As Integer
Dim M As Integer
Dim FirstWSToSort As Integer
Dim LastWSToSort As Integer
Dim SortDescending As Boolean

SortDescending = False

If ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count = 1 Then

    FirstWSToSort = 1
    LastWSToSort = Worksheets.Count
Else
    With ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
        For N = 2 To .Count
            If .Item(N - 1).Index <> .Item(N).Index - 1 Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next N
        FirstWSToSort = .Item(1).Index
        LastWSToSort = .Item(.Count).Index
    End With
End If

For M = FirstWSToSort To LastWSToSort
    For N = M To LastWSToSort
        If SortDescending = True Then
            If UCase(Worksheets(N).Name) > UCase(Worksheets(M).Name) Then
                Worksheets(N).Move Before:=Worksheets(M)
            End If
        Else
            If UCase(Worksheets(N).Name) < UCase(Worksheets(M).Name) Then
                Worksheets(N).Move Before:=Worksheets(M)
            End If
        End If
    Next N
Next M

End Sub
```

Comment: The values shown because both are from different data source. What's you mean 'Classic' style? @pnuts

Comment: Thanks @pnuts , it does change the appearance and nearly just like I need :) But I still wonder how the **Row Labels** header appear if I manually drag and drop any column which using 'Date' type data, not the name of actual column header (as example : **Month Opened** header.

Comment: @IlhamideaZ : What is the function called after this one? Could you please post the code of this function and the code that is calling `AgingFur` and this next one? And what is left for the Pivot Table formatting to fix?

Comment: @R3uK I'm already edit the questions. The code executed before also a Pivot Table but can directly execute **SortWorksheets** function but not if I execute **AgingFur**.

Comment: @IlhamideaZ : Can you add *SortWorksheets* too plz?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line into the `AgingFur` procedure

```
objTable.RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
```

before this line

```
objTable.PivotCache.Refresh
```